# Schedule R scripts in AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, etl

There are several R scripts that need to be run periodically. Currently, i am having an EC2 instance where these R scripts are running through Cron jobs. However, this is not cost efficient as the scripts do not run all the time.

I am looking for a service that lets me deploy the R scripts and schedule them, only paying per use. Something like for instance AWS Lambda does.

Note: Rewrite these scripts is not a solution for now, since there are many and I do not have the resources for it.

Any ideas or suggestions about it?

Comment: You can deploy your script in a package to Lambda and schedule it to run, I believe. I'm sure there's a lot of reading material on this matter out there, see [here](https://dev.to/byrro/how-to-schedule-any-task-with-aws-lambda-3617) for example.

Comment: Thank, nonetheless one of the limitations for Lambda is its 15 min maximum duration. It also requires some additional efforts to run R, as it is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can containerize your scripts and try to run them on ECS with a cron schedule.

Quick search can give you plenty of examples on dockerizing R scripts, like [this](https://www.statworx.com/de/blog/running-your-r-script-in-docker/).

You can push your resulting images to AWS ECR, which is docker registry, and use images to define ECR tasks: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html

After that you can [run your tasks on schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html).

This way scripts will only consume compute power while working. It still requires some refactoring in form of containerization, but after you do this once it should scale to all other scripts.

If containerization is still too much work, you can combine EC2 [instance scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler/) with [reserved scheduled instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-scheduled-instances.html) for savings, but be aware that reserved instances have a lot of limitations if you plan on savings.

Comment: Thank you, i already did and found two disadvantages:  
  
1) CloudWatch alarms can not be set to monitor a period longer than a day, which leaves the scripts running in a bigger frequency "unmonitored". 
2) It does not let you "retry" if the task fails.